# Login to web via wp7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

how can I make login to my page with wp7 app?

I have buttons for email and password and when user clicks on Log in, it will submit via POST to my webpage and opens web browser component with loaded webpage.

I have problem with that POST submit.

Comment: please show the code you have the specific problem with

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an [OAuth layer](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/) in your web application and then use the existing authentication model to login directly from your Windows Phone application. Logging in by sending raw data (either as parameters or headers) might be a big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to have a XAML page that takes the username and password then open a WebBrowser control logged in to your site?

You only really have two options I can think of, pass the username and password on the querystring (a really bad option) or return some form of token from your authentication POST that you can pass on the querystring to log the user in. The token would need to be unique and shortlived to avoid opening a gaping security hole.